# SDImageView - unrecognized error after 4.0 Upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, sdwebimage

I have update my pod file. Hence my sdwebimage pod file is updated to 4.0 and now I am getting lot of unrecognized issue and solved most of the issue.

Now I need some idea solve the bellow issue.

Feature for this code : I want to check whether the image is downloaded already or not with the help of URL for that I am using the below code

```
-(BOOL) isDownloadComplete:(NSString*)downloadmediaURL
{
    BOOL downloaded = NO;
    NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",downloadmediaURL];
    NSString * aURL = [url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];


    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

    if (![manager cachedImageExistsForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aURL]])
    {

        downloaded = NO;
    }
    else
    {

        downloaded = YES;


    }

    return downloaded;
}
```

But now I am getting unrecognized issue in the below line

```
if (![manager cachedImageExistsForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aURL]])
```

Let know how can I over come this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I need this function as BOOL function. Now its replaced as void function I am not able to check that condition at the time of loading that particular page

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage 4.0.0 is a major release and method cachedImageExistsForURL: is changed to have a completion handler.

```
/**
 *  Async check if image has already been cached
 *
 *  @param url              image url
 *  @param completionBlock  the block to be executed when the check is finished
 *  
 *  @note the completion block is always executed on the main queue
 */
- (void)cachedImageExistsForURL:(nullable NSURL *)url
                     completion:(nullable SDWebImageCheckCacheCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
```

You can use it like this -

```
[manager cachedImageExistsForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aURL] completion:(Bool isInCache) {
   if (isInCache) {
     //Image present in cache
   }
}]
```